# Is there any way to modify an object by only being provided a function that references a property?

Tags: javascript, object

Strange question, but I am really curious if there is any way to accomplish this.

Lets say you have a function that returns you the value of an object:

```
(someObject) => someObject.someProp
```

Now I have a function that should update someProp of someObject. As input I have the function described above, and the new value for someProp:

```
const modifyObject = (getterFunction, newValue) => {
    // magic to set someObject.someProp to a new value
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, it's not possible to go from the value back to the property it came from.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you can work on the reference of it and return the original object, but I couldnt get it to work as it seems the reference is lost as soon as I get the value from the getter function

Comment: There are no reference objects in JS.

Comment: Why not just pass the property name?

Comment: Thats what I do now. Effectively, you define it as a string like "someObject.someProp" but this breaks the typing of the object. Obviously I cant get type suggestions etc on a string. So I thought it might be convenient to instead have a function, but I suppose I would have to make 2 functions for getter/setter

Comment: It seems like you're trying to emulate C-style pointers. There's nothing equivalent in JS.

Comment: How do you want to pass the object?

Comment: You could use a pair of setter/getter.

Comment: Yeah I think getter & setter might be the only solution to this problem